# Append plain text to variable value

Tags: .net, razor

I'm trying to generate fairly simple xml using razor template engine. 
This is my template:

```xml
<gridDef Id="@Model.MasterType.Name"/>
```

I would like to append "Grid" to Id attribute value.
It works with code block:

```
@{
  var name = Model.MasterType.Name + "Grid";
}
<gridDef Id="@name"/>
```

but I would like to use razor syntax without defining variables. Is that possible?

Comment: hm, so you have to generate an xml file. Why don't you just return it as XML from your controller, you could also set the content type and setup a route to it as if it were a real file on the server.

Comment: I'm using it in console application for xml files generation.

Comment: @Filip: You should use LINQ to XML instead.

Comment: @Slaks Can you explain this a little bit. I need to generate rather complicated xml file based on domain object metadata and chosen template. Are you suggesting that I should implement it in code using LINQ to XML instead of using template engine?

Comment: @Filip: Yes.  `new XElement(name, new XAttribute(...), new XElement(...), LINQ query, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to separate the Razor expression from the literal source:

```
<gridDef Id="@(Model.MasterType.Name)Grid" />
```

Alternatively, you could concatenate the string within the expression:

```
<gridDef Id="@(Model.MasterType.Name + "Grid")" />
```